# Multiple deployment profiles with fabric8

Tags: maven, kubernetes, fabric8

Does the maven-fabric8-plugin have the ability to support multiple profiles for different Kubernetes clusters?

I have no problem building the resources and deploying to a local minikube instance and my yaml files are under `src/main/fabric8`.

However I would like to be able to specify different profiles such as

- `src/main/fabric8/local` for local deployment on minikube
- `src/main/fabric8/dev` to deploy on the development cluster

What are the recommended approaches to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem had an easy answer. I ended up populating the profiles with the `src/main/fabric8` directory and then in my maven build I specify the profile using the `-Dfabric.resourceDir` flag